# How to word wrap the hint of a single line AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView where the user is to write in a single-line search, i.e. no line breaks are allowed. Using `android:singleLine="true"` allows this to work properly.

However, I also wish to set a hint to display when no other text has been entered, and this text does require more than one line. My problem is that with Android 4+, the hint is not wrapped to several lines. With Android 2.3, however, the content does get wrapped and multiple lines are displayed. Users are still not able enter more than one line, so this is the way I want it.

Using for example `android:maxLines="2"` does not help since that allows the user to insert a line break when searching. I've also tried `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` and `android:ellipsize="none"` and `android:layout_weight=1` without success.

Any ideas on how I can get the hint to wrap multiple lines and still only accept a single line from users with Android 4 as well? Below is the code I'm using at the moment.

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:completionThreshold="3"
        android:hint="This is the hint to be displayed. It's rather long and doesn't fit in one line"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing singleLine to:

```
android:lines="1"
```

And now to disable "Enter":

EDIT_TEXT.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That gets the appearance right, but unfortunately allows you to enter line breaks as well.

Comment: Then you can add onKeyListener to your EditText and return true if the keyCode is enter key. Updated the anser as well

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an OnFocusChangeListener to change the value of `singleLine` or `maxLines`:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange (View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // This might do it on its own
        ((AutoCompleteTextView) v).setSingleLine(hasFocus);

        // If setSingleLine() doesn't work try this 
        AutoCompleteTextView auto = (AutoCompleteTextView) v;
        if(hasFocus)
            auto.setMaxLines(1);
        else
            auto.setMaxLines(2); // or more if necessary

        // Only keep the one that works, you obviously don't need both!
    }
});
```

Comment: Close! Only problem is that my AutoCompleteTextView seems to get the focus by default and it's actually very hard to get it away from focus because all it has is a listview below it. It's pretty much on constant focus.

Comment: Oh boo, if there is nothing else to take the focus then: no this won't work... Glad you got a solution.