# Wrap hint text on SearchView Android

Tags: android, searchview

I need to wrap the **hint** text that is written inside the `SearchView`. How can I achieve this?

With the next code the text is shown like this: "This is a very lo..."

Here is my SearchView:

```
<SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:queryHint="This is a very long searchview hint"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

---

**Edit**

I was able to do this programmatically:

```
int id = mSvBusqueda.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText editText = (EditText) mSvBusqueda.findViewById(id);
editText.setSingleLine(false);
```

But I cant make the searchview container to wrap the edit text (see picture)

[image: Searchview not wrapping content]

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:lines="1"
```

And now to disable "Enter":

```
EDIT_TEXT.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[How to word wrap the hint of a single line AutoCompleteTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664764/how-to-word-wrap-the-hint-of-a-single-line-autocompletetextview)

Comment: mmm "lines" is not an attribute for SearchView. And I am not using an EditText, I am using SearchView.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: nope, this didn't work. BTW the attribute ellipsize doesn't appear for SearchView